# FormBuilder using prompt buttons to confirm form answered

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I have a bot using a FormBuilder to get answers. 
At the end, he asks automatically: "Is this your selection?", waiting a confirmation from user through keyboard (he needs to write yes/no).
Could I change this mode to buttons (YES) (NO) ? 
Also, Can I change easily the confirmation message?

Channel: Facebook

Thanks!

Comment: I was able to change the confirmation message, I used the Confirm () method and added response options in the Configuration.Yes and Configuration.No properties as a string array.
I just have not figured out how to turn these confirmations into clickable buttons...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible.

With C#, assume is part of your build form implementation:

```
...
.Confirm("Please confirm your input {||}")
...
```

Using {||} you can render the buttons yes / no.

Considerations:

- In my case, the {||} brokes the markdown of the text. I need to display first a large text with .Message("") using markdown and after it a simple .Confirm("")
- When use the {||} don't print a large text in the confirm because the message will be cut. I see this with Skype, Telegram, Slack (but they give you an option for view the large message) and webchat.